# Prove convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin(1/n)/n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove convergence of $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$.
bounded by 2.

I have tried a lot,
without any success.

Comment: so include your efforts in the question

Comment: We success to proove that the series increases.
But i am stack about the converegetion.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x)<x$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Since $1/n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, maybe you could consider $\sin(1/n)$ in a neighbourhood of $0$, e.g. $\sin(1/n)\to1/n$ as $n\to\infty$...

Comment: Hint 1: as Wojowu said, $\sin x < x$ for positive $x$. Hint 2: $\sum\limits_n {\frac 1{n^2}}$ converges.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: For $0<x<\pi$ we have $0<\sin x<x$.

Hint to the upper bound proof: $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}<\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ (why is this true?).

Comment: How can i use that ?

Comment: @NirMovshovitz The goal is to use the direct comparison test.

Answer (score 3):

As it is a series with positive terms, you can use equivalents:
$$\sin\frac1n\sim_\infty\frac1n\quad\text{hence}\quad\frac{\sin\frac1n}{n}\sim_\infty\frac1{n^2}$$
which is convergent, so the given series is convergent.

Comment: And how this helps me ?

Comment: It proves convergence.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\lim_n \frac{\sin\frac1n}{\frac1n}=1$. Therefore, using limit comparison test, we get
$$\lim_n \frac{\frac{\sin\frac1n}{n}}{\frac1{n^2}}=\lim_n\frac{\sin\frac1n}{\frac1n}=1.$$
Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2}$ converges (it's actually equal to $\frac{\pi^2}6$), $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\frac1k}{k}$ also converges.